# Setting up virtual environment using conda but using pip inside it

Tags: python, python3, pip, anaconda

I am new to setting up virtual environments and have failed to find a guide that fulfills my purpose.
I want to achieve the following :
OS - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I want to setup my machine so I have two virtual environments

1. For pip work
2. For conda work

I want to do this so in one virtual environment I can have all libraries that are installed using pip and in the other I can have all my anaconda work/libraries

For pip and conda both I want to a have Python3.6 as default

How can I do this ?

If this isn't possible can't I just create a virtual environment using conda and use pip inside it? If I remove that environment it will just delete all the libraries alongside the pip ones too.

PLEASE ASK FOR ANY ADDITIONAL INFO THAT'S REQUIRED. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible but is not clear what is your problem.

Conda by default, when you install python in the environment install also pip.

Create your environment for conda packages.

```
conda create -n conda_test -y python3.6
conda activate cond_test
conda install -y numpy
```

Create your environment for pip packages.

```
conda create -n pip_test -y python3.6
conda activate pip_test
pip install numpy
```